# Maven java error on compilation

Tags: java, presto

Please help me understand this error. BTW, this is not the latest version of presto. We are customizing it with our own settings. When I build it, get this following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project presto-connector:     Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/builder/presto/presto-connector/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/connector/S3PartitionManager.java:[711,118] incompatible types: com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveType cannot be converted to com.facebook.presto.spi.type.Type
[ERROR] /home/builder/presto/presto-connector/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/connector/BackgroundS3SplitLoader.java:[267,90] incompatible types: java.util.List<com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveSplit> cannot be converted to com.facebook.presto.spi.ConnectorSplit
[ERROR] /home/builder/presto/presto-connector/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/connector/BackgroundS3SplitLoader.java:[330,60] incompatible types: java.util.List<com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveSplit> cannot be converted to com.facebook.presto.spi.ConnectorSplit
[ERROR] /home/builder/presto/presto-connector/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/connector/BackgroundS3SplitLoader.java:[357,56] incompatible types: java.util.List<com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveSplit> cannot be converted to com.facebook.presto.spi.ConnectorSplit
[ERROR] /home/builder/presto/presto-connector/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/connector/BackgroundS3SplitLoader.java:[382,60] incompatible types: java.util.List<com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveSplit> cannot be converted to com.facebook.presto.spi.ConnectorSplit
```

**Maven version**

```
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d;
2017-10-18T07:58:13Z) 

Maven home: /opt/maven 
Java version: 1.8.0_151,
vendor: Oracle Corporation 
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.amzn2.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, 
platform encoding: UTF-8 
OS name: "linux",
version: "4.9.76-38.79.amzn2.x86_64", 
arch: "amd64", 
family: "unix"
```

Comment: This problem is obviously unrelated to Maven.  Please learn to understand these kind of obvious compilation error.  You are converting `HiveType` to `Type`, and converting `List<HiveSplit>` to `ConnectorSplit` which are invalid (I dunno what those classes is though)

Comment: Could you please have a look at code below and advise on mistakes?

Comment: What we mentioned here and the compiler error should already be clear enough for your to spot the problem of your code isn't it? Check clearly the APIs that you are using

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors on your code.
As the error log says :

- `S3PartitionManager` Line No. 711.
- `BackgroundS3SplitLoader` Line No. 267, 330, 357 and 382

You are converting the objects into incompatible types.

**Eg.** : Converting `com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveType` into `com.facebook.presto.spi.type.Type` is incompatible.

Comment: Have shared the codes for reference:
[BackgroundS3SplitLoader.java](https://codeshare.io/50jjD8)
[HiveSplit.java](https://codeshare.io/2WPPvM)
[ConnectorSplit.java](https://codeshare.io/GL994g)
[HiveType.java](https://codeshare.io/5MJJvp)
[Type.java](https://codeshare.io/5Pzz7Y)